# Adding new divs with custom classes to products on WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, loop, hooks

In a custom Wordpress theme I need to display product image and product summary side by side on the WooCommerce shop page, so I am trying to add new divs with custom Bootstrap classes;

I used `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` hook to add new div with classes as a parent to the product summary and it worked perfectly,
I tried using this code for the image

```
function wc_add_classes_img () {
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'wc_add_classes_img');

function wc_close_div_after_img () {
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_close_div_after_img' );
```

but it added new div as a parent of the product thumbnail that is a child of the `<a>` element, so the html output is

```
<li>
   <a>
      <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
          <img>       
      </div>
   </a>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
   </div>
</li>
```

instead of desired

```
<li>
   <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
      <a><img></a>    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
   </div>
</li>
```

Are there any other hooks I should be using?
Or maybe i am approaching this wrong and there is a better way to achieve the side-by-side image and summary layout?

Comment: So far I have achieved the desired side-by-side appearance by floating the summary to the right and displaying `<div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">` as  `inline-flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not edit the template file instead of using hooks?

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/content-product.php

> - This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.

A small example

```php
<li <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is another way to approach this problem, I just want to avoid editing templates if possible because I'm worried about potential conflicts when WooCommerce is updated. Or am I wrong?

Comment: As long as you are going to correctly overwrite the template files, see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1 
they will give no or no less/more conflicts with regard to the use of hooks

Comment: Ok, thanks again!